# What options are available to get a value that is associated to a key in yaml?

Tags: yaml

I often used jq to lookup a value in json. How to do this in yaml? I do not want to use something like sed as too much characters have to be removed then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One could use [go-yq](https://github.com/030/go-yq) if one wants to lookup a value by applying jq style, i.e. if firefox_version then one could look it up by adding a dot:

> ```
> docker run -v ${PWD}:/ansible-firefox utrecht/go-yq:2.1.0 \
>        .firefox_version /ansible-firefox/defaults/main.yml
> ```